# What qualifies as an algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, class

```
class Athlete:
  def __init__(self, name, points):
    self.name = name
    self.points = points

  def calculateRacePoints(name):
    for i in range(eventTotalVar):
      racePoints = checkOverallPlacement(placementVar, eventType=eventVar) + checkPercentagePlacement(placementVar, totalVar, eventType=eventVar) + checkImprovement(seedTime, prelimTime, finalTime) # uses created 2 functions and finds the total
      racePoints = racePoints + racePoints

    return float(racePoints / eventTotalVar)
```

This is basically creating an `athlete` with inputted specifications. It will return the average points attained in the race (total points divided by number of events).

Do `classes` qualify as an algorithm? If so, do my two functions within it also qualify as an algorithm? What *specifically* makes an algorithm, well, an algorithm?

Comment: An algorithm is a step-by-step procedure guaranteed to terminate after a finite number of steps. Without knowing what problem is to be solved, it's impossible to speculate what it means for your algorithm to "include two or more [other] algorithms".

Comment: @chepner I edited the question.

Comment: A method defined by the class may *implment* an algorithm, and a step-by-step plan for *using* the class can be considered an algorithm. But a class itself is not an algorithm.

Comment: @chepner Would a call to that class, such as `athlete = Athlete(athleteName, Athlete.calculateRacePoints(athleteName))`, be an algorithm?

Comment: If you can describe what question it answers or what problem it solves, sure. But it's a trivial one, as all the work is being done *inside* `calculateRacePoints`.

Comment: For example, a chocolate-chip cookie is not an algorithm. But a recipe that tells you have to *make* a batch of chocolate-chip cookies is.

Comment: Next to what has already been said, an algorithm comprises a characterization of inputs it operates on and of output it generates. Independence from a specific technical implementation would also be a common expectation. A function call in a specific programming language requiring a specific runtime thus would not qualify -  otoh, you may consider a programming language the vocabulary to describe the algorithm - ymmv.

Comment: Oh, man.  I’d love to go on a long lecture about Turing machines and the Church-Turing Thesis.  Perhaps this is not the venue, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oxford Dictionary defines an Algorithm as:

> "A process or set of rules to be followed in calculations or other
>   problem-solving operations, especially by a computer".

By that definition something as simple as `print("Hello World")` would technically be considered an algorithm.

looking at your code:

```
class Athlete:
  def __init__(self, name, points):
    self.name = name
    self.points = points

  def calculateRacePoints(name):
    for i in range(eventTotalVar):
      racePoints = checkOverallPlacement(placementVar, eventType=eventVar) + checkPercentagePlacement(placementVar, totalVar, eventType=eventVar) + checkImprovement(seedTime, prelimTime, finalTime) # uses created 2 functions and finds the total
      racePoints = racePoints + racePoints

    return float(racePoints / eventTotalVar)
```

You have multiple algorithms at work.

**class Athlete**

- Contains two or more algorithms
- Contains logical and mathematical concepts

**def __init__(self, name, points)**

- Solves the problem of describing who or what the athlete is
- It allows you to create an athlete and give that athlete a name and score/points

**def calculateRacePoints(name)**

- Solves the problem of interacting with the athlete
- It allows you to get information about this athlete's score/points

Both of your class methods are algorithms that work together to help the program create new athletes and interact with them.

I would imagine you need to provide more detail to complete the assignment, but I hope this gets you started.